# How to insert data in many to many relationship

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am using code first database model in my project. I am stuck in a many to many relationship insert issue. Here is my database schema:

```
public class Question
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  .....
  .......

  [CustomRequiredValidation]
  Public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime LastEditDate { get; set; }
  .....
  .......


  Public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Now in form post i am sending Question object containing Tags. But tag object contains only name and id of the already saved tags. Now can anyone please tell me how i can insert my Question object in the database so that Many to Many relational table between Question and Tag will also get entry ??

**Edit :**

I am adding the validation attribute on the navigation collection property (*Tags in Question entity*). Is this correct place to validate tags for Question ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is attach your `Tag` objects to your context before saving changes. You do this by using `context.Tags.Attach(tag)`. That way, Entity Framework knows that your entity already exists and won't try to insert a duplicate.

Here is a console application that demonstrates this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            ctx.Database.Delete();

            Question q1 = new Question
            {
                Title = "Title1",
                Tags = new List<Tag> 
                    { 
                        new Tag {Name = "Tag1", CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow, LastEditDate = DateTime.UtcNow },
                        new Tag {Name = "Tag2", CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow, LastEditDate = DateTime.UtcNow }, 
                        new Tag {Name = "Tag3", CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow, LastEditDate = DateTime.UtcNow }, 
                    }
            };

            ctx.Questions.Add(q1);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        Question q2 = new Question
            {
                Title = "Title1",
                Tags = new List<Tag> 
                    { 
                        new Tag {Id = 1, Name = "Tag1"},
                    }
            };

        using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            foreach (Tag t in q2.Tags)
            {
                DbEntityEntry<Tag> entry = ctx.Entry(t);
                if (entry.State == System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
                {
                    ctx.Tags.Attach(t);
                }
            }

            ctx.Questions.Add(q2);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastEditDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

After running this console application you will see that a new link between your second question and the first tag is inserted into the QuestionsTag table.